# Jenkins - Inheriting environment variables on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, environment-variables, ubuntu-14.04

I'm looking to set an environmental variable on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine which we need in our build. But whenever I run the build from Jenkins it's not finding the variable.

I've set the variable in

- /etc/environment
- /etc/profile
- /etc/bash.bashrc
- ~/.profile
- ~/.bashrc

and though I can see the variable from the machines terminal it does not show up when I run a job on Jenkins.

My client connects to Jenkins using Java WebStart. It is a Startup Application on Ubuntu.

This seems like it should be a simple thing to do. But I've wasted a few hours struggle with it (which is frustrating).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I need to do this too. Were you ever able to get this to work?

Comment: In the end I had to set the environmental variables on Jenkins :(

Comment: That's what I thought!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way to manage environment variables is to do so from within Jenkins.

Click on "Build Executor Status" on the main page to get to the nodes page, choose the node in question, hit Configure, and under the "Node Properties" section check the "Environment variables".

There you can add environment variables which will be available during a build.

You can also do this globally, for all Jenkins build machines, under Configure System > Global properties.

Comment: I'm familiar with how Jenkins can configure environmental variables per Node and Globally. But I'm hoping to use the variable on the machine itself. This would allow me to remote onto the machine and build without needing to set variables myself. It would also mean there is no need to duplicate the variables. i.e. Once on the machine and once on Jenkins,

Comment: As mentioned above I was forced to compromise and set the variables on Jenkins. I'm reluctantly marking as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

An awkward workaround described by [CloudBees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/229724088-How-to-set-up-a-Jenkins-agent-to-have-the-same-path-as-the-user-when-connected-via-Remote-Desktop-) is to set

```
PermitUserEnvironment yes
```

in the build agent system's sshd configuration file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (and restart the sshd service) and then add the environment variable assignment to the file `~/.ssh/environment` for the Jenkins agent user account (and reconnect from the Jenkins master).

Comment: I'm not going to try verify that. But you sir get 2 thumbs up for effort.